# Wordpress Ajax insertion is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hi i am creating popup plugin in `WordPress` for that i am inserting data in database through ajax. My code for the popup plugin everything is working fine till jQuery but after that the data is not inserting into database.

Well this code is working fine for me now. Thanks for all your help

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: SMS POPUP PLUGIN
Description: SMS POPUP PLUGIN
Version: 1.0
License: Plugin comes under GPL Licence.
*/



if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '3.9', '<' ) )  {
     wp_die("You must update WordPress to use SMS Factory Bulk SMS Service!");
  }

include_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
function sfp_popup() {

                global $wpdb, $wnm_db_version;

                $sfp_sql = array();

                //sms table
                $sfp_content = $wpdb->prefix . "sfp_content";

                if( $wpdb->get_var("show tables like '". $sfp_content . "'") !== $sfp_content ) { 

                    $sfp_sql[] = "CREATE TABLE ". $sfp_content . " ( sfp_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, sfp_name varchar(256) NOT NULL, sfp_phone int(11) NOT NULL, sfp_pwd varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, sfp_email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, sfp_query varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (sfp_id) ) ";
                }


                if ( !empty($sfp_sql) ) {
                    require_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
                    dbDelta($sfp_sql);
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
                    add_option("wnm_db_version", $wnm_db_version);

                }

        }

        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'sfp_popup'); 

        add_action( 'wp_head', 'enque_sfp_script', 100 );
        function enque_sfp_script(){
            //Include Javascript library
            wp_enqueue_script('sfp_script', plugins_url( '/js/demo.js' , __FILE__ ) , array( 'jquery' ));
            // including ajax script in the plugin Myajax.ajaxurl
            wp_localize_script( 'sfp_script', 'sfpAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
        }

        function sfp_insert(){
            global $wpdb;
            $sfp_table = $wpdb->prefix."sfp_content";
            $name = $_POST['sf_name'];
            $phone = $_POST['sf_phone'];
            $message = $_POST['sf_message'];


                $wpdb->insert( 
                    $sfp_table, 
                    array( 
                        'sfp_name' => $name,
                        'sfp_phone' => $phone,
                        'sfp_query' => $message
                    ), 
                    array( 
                        '%s',
                        '%d',
                        '%s'
                    ) 
                );
            die();
            return true;
        }

    add_action('wp_ajax_sfp_insert', 'sfp_insert');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sfp_insert', 'sfp_insert');

    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'sf_display_popup', 100 );

function sf_display_popup(){
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        setTimeout(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }, 3000);


            $( "#sf-popup .sfname" ).keyup(function() {
              if($(this).val() == '' || $( "#sf-popup .sfphone").val() == ''){
                    $('#sfpsubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');

                } else{
                    $('#sfpsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $( ".sfp_btn" ).click(function() {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    });
                }
            });

            $( "#sf-popup .sfphone" ).keyup(function() {
                var sfp_phone = $(this).val();              
                if(sfp_phone.length > 10){
                    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,10));
                    $('#sfpsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
                }   

                    if(sfp_phone == '' || $( "#sf-popup .sfname").val() == '' || $.isNumeric(sfp_phone) == false ||  sfp_phone.length < 10){
                    $('#sfpsubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');

                } else{
                    $('#sfpsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $( ".sfp_btn" ).click(function() {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    });
                }
                });

        });

</script>

<style>
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}

textarea.col-md-12 {
    margin: 25px 0;
}
</style>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
<?php   

        echo "<form method='post' action='' name='sf-popup' id='sf-popup' >";
        echo "<input type='text' name='sf_name' id='sf_name' placeholder='Name' class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 sfname'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='sf_phone' id='sf_phone' placeholder='98765-43210' class='col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 sfphone'>";
        echo "<textarea name='sf_message' id='sf_message' placeholder='Enter Your Query' class='col-md-12'></textarea>";
        echo "</form>";     
?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <?php
                    echo "<button id='sfpsubmit' class='btn btn-primary sfp_btn' name='sfpsubmit' disabled>Submit</button>";

                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

and this is my jquery code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#sfpsubmit").click(function(){

        var name = jQuery("#sf_name").val();

        var phone = jQuery("#sf_phone").val();
        var message = jQuery("#sf_message").val();
        alert(name + phone + message);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: sfpAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {action: "sfp_insert","sf_name":name,"sf_phone":phone,"sf_message":message},
            success: function(data){
            alert("success"+data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing is showing in console. in `alert(data)` it is showing 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this data:

`data: {action: "post_word_count", sf_name:name},`

use this debugin function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_post_word_count', 'post_word_count'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post_word_count', 'post_word_count'); 
    function post_word_count(){
    echo $_POST['sf_name'];
    die();
    }
```

Comment: what does the alert display "nothing happens" is not very helpful

Comment: Okay when i do click on button the `alert(data)` is showing 0 that's it the value is not coming in `echo $_POST['sf_name'];`

Comment: in the documentation is before you should do that too

Comment: if you don't have luck with post try it with get `type: 'GET',` and php `echo $_GET['sf_name'];`

Comment: My js code is in another file and the php code is in the another file

Comment: put you php in function.php of the theme try again

Comment: I have updated my answer can you please check now it insert the data only one time don't know how after that it stop working

Comment: i mean it did insert data only one time now it is not working again getting 0 after inserting data on form

Comment: your submit button is disable

Comment: That is just a validation i am removing it through jquery as you can see on my php code

Comment: you need `wp_ajax_sfp_post_word_count ` in your hooks

Comment: Thanks for your help it helps me a lot but my code is working fine now 

actually the problem is when i was creating table i was giving `sfp_name varchar(128) NOT NULL` then i do change the 128 to 256 and now it is working absolutely fine

Comment: glad to know, good luck in your wild and unpredictable adventure in the world of programming

Comment: Well really i was shocked that this thing can effect on code i spent all my day on it and at the end found this

Comment: Thanks for your support buddy

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have enqueued the script then localized it ..

It should be first register then localize then Enqueue.

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

> I have not tested your method , but this one is working for me.

Comment: his script is running so the problem is not with the placing of the script

Comment: yes my script is working fine only problem is in inserting data into database. and i wanna clear that i have six fields in database but i am  inserting one

Comment: can you please tell  the name and location of your php file

Comment: hi @PrakashRao i am creating this in local and all my php code is in one file and js in another file